# how to build three.js from sources

Tags: build, compilation, three.js, rebuild

I'm having some trouble getting `three.js` to build -
the resulting `three.js` file is significantly different than what I downloaded.

This is likely related to the comment "This page is currently invalid and needs to be rewritten" on this page in the wiki, ["How to generate a compressed Three"](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/build.py, -or-how-to-generate-a-compressed-Three.js-file).

Nonetheless, I'm a bit up a tree.

I'd like to add collision exclusion to `Raycaster.js/intersectObject()`,
but rebuilding breaks my app without errors or warnings in the console.

I've tried with various permutations of the possible `--include`'s,
with varying but unsuccessful results.

I'm not even trying to build the minified version.

I'm on OSX.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a terminal window go to utils/build and run:

```
python build.py --include common --include extras --output ../../build/three.js
```

Or... run the [shell file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/build/build.sh):

```
./build.sh
```

Comment: works perfect - the output is identical. thanks, i should have figured that out.